# How would i create a price calculator with 1 input and 6 different outputs?

Tags: html, input, output, calculator

I have created an initial version, however you have to type the individual inputs for each output. I want to be able to just type into one input box and then it calculates all other outputs. How would i do this?

This is the code i have currently, im very very new to this :)

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber /0.7).toFixed(0)" <br>
  NHS <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" placeholder="NHS" <br> TO <input name="o" id="o" type="number" for="a" placeholder="RETAIL"></output> Retail


</form>

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber *1).toFixed(0)" <br>
  NHS <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" placeholder="NHS" <br> TO <input name="o" id="o" type="number" for="a" placeholder="Schools & CDC's"></output> Schools & CDC's


</form>

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber / 0.7 -(a.valueAsNumber / 0.7 / 100*40)).toFixed(0)" <br>
  NHS <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" placeholder="NHS" <br> TO <input name="o" id="o" type="number" for="a" placeholder="Trade - Band A" Math.round></output> Trade - Band A


</form>

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber *1).toFixed(0)" <br>
  NHS <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" placeholder="NHS" <br> TO <input name="o" id="o" type="number" for="a" placeholder="Trade - Band B"></output> Trade - Band B


</form>

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber / 0.7 -(a.valueAsNumber / 0.7 / 100*20)).toFixed(0)" <br>
  NHS <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" placeholder="NHS" <br> TO <input name="o" id="o" type="number" for="a" placeholder="Trade - Band C" Math.round></output> Trade - Band C


</form>

<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="o.value = (a.valueAsNumber / 0.7 -(a.valueAsNumber / 0.7 / 100*10)).toFixed(0)" <br>
  NHS <input name="a" id="a" type="number" step="any" placeholder="NHS" <br> TO <input name="o" id="o" type="number" for="a" placeholder="Trade - Band D" Math.round></output> Trade - Band D


</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5gpLbj80/2/

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code?

Comment: No, im pretty sure the code works - i just don't want to individually put the inputs for the 6 different outputs, if that makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried to avoid that? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I would like to have just the one input box that changes all of the outputs - i was creating this as a html calculator from one that i already have made from excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First piece of advice would be to remove all of those inline event handlers.
Attach a named function, then do all of your grunt-work inside it.
By using addEventListener to connect the two, the function 'knows' which element it's attached to. That is to say, we can simply use `this.value` to get it's value, rather than having to use `document.getElementById('nhs').value`

```js
"use strict;"
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt)
{
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value))
  {
    outputs[0].textContent = value * 2;
    outputs[1].textContent = value * 3;
    outputs[2].textContent = parseInt( (value * 3)/4 );
  }
  else
  {
    outputs[0].textContent = 
    outputs[1].textContent = 
    outputs[2].textContent = "*invalid input (enter a number)*";
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Enter data: <input id='myInput'/></label><br>
<ul>
  <li id='output1'></li>
  <li id='output2'></li>
  <li id='output3'></li>
</ul>
```

### Alternate snippet

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict;"
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
  let input = byId('myInput');
  input.addEventListener('input', onInputReceived, false);
}

function onInputReceived(evt)
{
  let outputs = [byId('output1'), byId('output2'), byId('output3')];
  let value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if (!isNaN(value))
  {
    outputs[0].textContent = value * 2;
    outputs[1].textContent = value * 3;
    outputs[2].textContent = parseInt( (value * 3)/4 );
  }
  else
  {
    outputs[0].textContent = 
    outputs[1].textContent = 
    outputs[2].textContent = "*invalid input (enter a number)*";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Enter data: <input id='myInput'/></label><br>
    <ul>
      <li id='output1'></li>
      <li id='output2'></li>
      <li id='output3'></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would i be able to use this in dreamweaver, every time i copy and paste it and try to preview the live code nothing happens and it just appears as text rather than running the code like on this website, do you know why this may be? @enhzflep

Comment: @Lewis - something to be aware of in case you aren't, is that runnable code-snippets here at SO appear to lump the html and the javascript and the css all together, in a single blob. As such, you have to copy and paste the parts individually. I'll edit my answer to include something you'll find more familiar.

Comment: I see the new one and it has worked thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Lewis - fantastic, glad I could assist. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same input to update all your fields, no need to use a form.

```js
const calc = () => {
  let nhs = document.getElementById('nhs').value;
  document.getElementById('retail').innerHTML = (nhs / 0.7).toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById('school').innerHTML = (nhs * 1).toFixed(0);
  //If you want an input:
  document.getElementById('retailInput').value = (nhs / 0.7).toFixed(0);
  document.getElementById('schoolInput').value = (nhs * 1).toFixed(0);

}
```

```html
NHS<input id='nhs' oninput='calc()'><br>
<span>Retail:</span><span id='retail'></span><br>
<span>School:</span><span id='school'></span><br>
<span>Retail input:</span><input id='retailInput' disabled='true' /><br>
<span>Retail input:</span><input id='schoolInput' disabled='true' />
```

Comment: Ah i see, then i would just add the other 4 different outputs?

Comment: A reasonable solution. One minor detail though, if I may - by listening for a key event (key-up) you make the input dead to pasting values with the mouse. Listening for the `input` event (oninput) means you get called whether its a mouse interraction or a keyboard one that supplies a value.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @enhzflep, the solution has been updated

Comment: Yes @Lewis just follow the same logic for all your other fields

Comment: @Lewis please accept the answer if this solution solves your problem.

Comment: @HassenCh. i just copy and pasted the code into dreamweaver and tried to preview the code but its not working the same as it does here on the website?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dreamweaver @Lewis

Comment: @HassenCh. No worries thank you, what language was this code written in; html or Javascript?

Comment: There are two parts, the first is in javascript, the second is in HTML. I suggest that you follow a course on the basics of HTML, Javascript and CSS